# Deleting a cell from a table when clicking a button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My question is: There is a ViewController on which the table is located. It is populated from CoreData with this all right. I need to implement cell deletion when I click on the button in the right corner of the cell.

I know how to implement removal when swipe, but this is not it. It is necessary when pressing. I was looking for a similar problem, but I did not find something, I apologize if I repeat. How can I do that?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. 
You need to write following code to your button tap event.

`tableView.beginUpdates()
yourDataArray.remove(at: IndexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath], with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()`

Comment: There is no point of doing `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` **from apple doc** _Begins a series of method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and sections of the table view._

Comment: And BTW: _Use the_ `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` _method instead of this one whenever possible._